# Substitution in a complex lambda calculus formula

Tags: substitution, lambda-calculus

I have the following lambda expression:

$$( (y \lambda x \rightarrow \lambda y \rightarrow f y) (\lambda f \rightarrow f y z) )[y := f x]$$

So, my questions are,

- I see $y$ before a lambda abstraction, what does that mean ? Is that y free ?
- Is it correct to put parenthesis like this in the expression ?

$$(y (\lambda x \rightarrow \lambda y \rightarrow f y)) (\lambda f \rightarrow f y z) )[y := f x]$$

Then, I would have the term $f x$ applied to the lambda expression:

$$(\lambda x \rightarrow \lambda y \rightarrow f y)$$

However, is that $f$ free ?

I learned, for example:

- a variable is bound if it is within the scope of a lambda term; otherwise, it is free.
- I can only substitute *free* occurrences of a variable.
- I should avoid variable capturing by using *alpha conversion*.

I thought I understood the basics of lambda calculus substitution, but I can't grasp this example. I clearly have gaps in my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the following lambda expression:
> $((yλx→λy→fy)(λf→fyz))[y:=fx]$

Uh, this is a weird syntax, I assume it should be read as $((yλx.λy.fy)(λf.fyz))[y:=fx]$.

> I see $y$ before a lambda abstraction, what does that mean ? Is that $y$ free ?

A variable (or more precisely, an occurrence of a variable) isn't free in general, but only free (or bound) in a given term. Here, the first occurrence of $y$ is indeed free in the term $(yλx→λy→fy)(λf→fyz)$. But in the whole term you give it is substituted, so it doesn't even exist as a “true” variable occurrence — and thus, is neither free nor bound. (The other occurrence of $y$ is bound by $\lambda y$ in any case.)

This is where the subtility of this example arises, because you substitute $fx$ to $y$ in a λ-expression where

- $y$ appears both free and bound, which may be overcome depending on the way you define substitution (see [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53003/is-it-necessary-to-apply-alpha-conversion-in-this-term-to-perform-beta-reduction/53004#53004));
- $f$ appears bound, which forbids substitution without performing α-conversion first.

The minimal conversion you must do is the following (I put the fresh variables in capital letters):

$((yλx→λy→fy)(λf→fyz))[y:=fx] \\
=_α ((yλx→λy→fy)(λF→Fyz))[y:=fx] \\
= ((fx)λx→λy→fy)(λF→F(fx)z)$

but it would be cleaner (and might be required by your definition of the substitution) to convert also the bound $y$:

$((yλx→λy→fy)(λf→fyz))[y:=fx] \\
=_α ((yλx→λY→fY)(λF→Fyz))[y:=fx] \\
= ((fx)λx→λY→fY)(λF→F(fx)z) $

> Is it correct to put parenthesis like this in the expression ?

I would say yes. But this depends on the way you defined the syntax of the λ-calculus, there are several valid choices for the scope of the constructors and the placing of the parentheses. (See the curious, yet very practical [Krivine notation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38894/krivines-notation-for-lambda-terms).)

> Then, I would have the term $fx$ applied to the lambda expression: $(λx→λy→fy)$. However, is that $f$ free ?

Yes, these two $f$ are free.

Comment: Thank you very much. What's your definition of fresh variable ?

Comment: It's a new variable that is not used anywhere else in the term. When you need, for some reason, to perform α-conversion on some $λx.x$, you take a new “fresh” variable $y$ (this is always possible because the set of variables is infinite) and you rewrite $λx.x$ to $λy.y$.

Comment: Thank you ! And do you know what happens in this case $(λy → (λz → z)) x$ ? Is it reduced to `(λz → z)`. I ask because lambda $y$ doesn't appear in the body.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Do you know whether I have to substitute both lambda expressions if I have: `(λx → x) (λy → y * x) [x:=z+z]` ? So, would I get: `(λx → z + z) (λy → y * (z + z))`. And why is that ? I think I should only substitute in the rightmost lambda expressions. I can't seem to find precedence rules for the substitution operation.

Comment: What you suggest is incorrect, the $x$ in $λx.x$ is bound and should not be substituted. About precedence rules: syntax is a matter of choice and taste, just fix a rule you like and stick to it. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant going from: `(λw → x + w) (λy → y * x) [x:=z+z]` to `(λw → (z+z) + w) (λy → y * (z+z)) [x:=z+z]`. Is sensible to replace both abstractions, or just the rightmost lambda abstraction ?

Comment: Using the syntax I'm used to I would just substitute in the right subterm, but again, *you* decide what is the scope of the substitution operation. (And `[x := z+z]` should disappear in the second expression.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I should remove that `[x := z+z]` in the second expression.